# Fill NaN value with the mean of the previous and the next row - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, google-colaboratory

I have to replace the NaN value of my dataset which is organised like this

SUBDIVISION: ANDAMAN & NICOBAR ISLANDS
YEAR: 1901
JAN: 49.20
FEB: 87.10
MAR: NaN
APR: 19.10
MAY: 89.99

(In reality there are all months of the year and the data are displayed in column)

I have to replace the NaN value with the mean of the previous (1900) and the next year (1902), and if it is possible adding to this operation also the values of the next month of the same year (APR 1901) doing the mean of this three values.

> ```
> import pandas as pd
> import numpy as np
> import statistics
> # Loop through rows of dataframe by index i.e. from 0 to number of rows
> for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
>   for j in range(1, df.shape[1]):  #iterate over columns
>    if pd.isna(df.iloc[i,j]):
>      adjacentYearBefore = df.iloc[i-1,j].mean()
>      adjacentYearAfter= df.iloc[i+1,j].mean()
>      #avgYear = ((np.float64(adjacentYearBefore)) + (np.float64(adjacentYearAfter))) / 2.0
>      avgYear = (adjacentYearBefore + adjacentYearAfter).mean()
>      print(avgYear)
>      df.iloc[i,j] = df.iloc[i,j].fillna(avgYear)
> ```

But return me this

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-32c064fa8ca4> in <module>()
     11      avgYear = (adjacentYearBefore + adjacentYearAfter).mean()
     12      print(avgYear)
---> 13      df.iloc[i,j] = df.iloc[i,j].fillna(avgYear)
     14      #df.iloc[i,j].ffill(inplace=True)
     15      #

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'fillna'
```

I've read of course the similar question on stack overflow, of course, but i still could not solve my problem.

**UPDATE**:

```py
df.head(10)
```

[output of df.head(10)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBlvr.png)

Comment: Please, can you update your post with the output of `df.head(10)` to understand the dataframe.

Comment: Check out `pandas.Series.interpolate` it does exactly what you want https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html.

Comment: the interpolation is linear or polynomial in my case?

Answer (score 3):

### My guess what you're actually asking:

My dataframe looks like this:

```
      annual
1901  3373.2
1902  3520.7
1903  2957.4
1904  3079.6
1905  2566.7
1906  2534.4
1907     NaN
1908  3576.4
1909  2899.4
1910  2687.2
```

How do I fill in the nan with the average of the year before and after?

### Answer:

```
df.interpolate()
```

gives

```
      annual
1901  3373.2
1902  3520.7
1903  2957.4
1904  3079.6
1905  2566.7
1906  2534.4
1907  3055.4
1908  3576.4
1909  2899.4
1910  2687.2
```

Have I guessed correctly what you're asking and are you happy with the solution? Notice btw. that this uses the default interpolation method that is `method=linear`.

### Further question: What is wrong with my code?

There are few things to notice about your code that maybe you can learn from. The `.mean` in

```
     adjacentYearBefore = df.iloc[i-1,j].mean()
     adjacentYearAfter = df.iloc[i+1,j].mean()
```

don't do anything since you're taking the mean of one value.

Same is true for

```
     avgYear = (adjacentYearBefore + adjacentYearAfter).mean()
```

Notice that you're first adding the two values and then taking the mean of that one value so you didn't divide by two.

And finally in

```
     df.iloc[i,j] = df.iloc[i,j].fillna(avgYear)
```

you are taking one value and call `fillna` on it. That is not possible since `fillna` is supposed to be called on a `series` or `dataframe` filling in all the values. Here you could just assign the value.

### Working version of your code:

```
for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
      for j in range(1, df.shape[1]):  #iterate over columns
            if pd.isna(df.iloc[i,j]):
                adjacentYearBefore = df.iloc[i-1,j]
                adjacentYearAfter= df.iloc[i+1,j]
                avgYear = (adjacentYearBefore + adjacentYearAfter)/2
                print(avgYear)
                df.iloc[i,j] = avgYear
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Please, check the image i posted. I want to replace ALL the NaN value of a column with the mean of the value of the previous and next year. So not only annual. It is possible to do this with the given algorithm in my solution? I runned your solution but the number of NaN values is the always the same.

Comment: By default this does it for all columns. But it returns a new dataframe with the inserted values. I suspect you check on the old dataframe where obviously nothing has changed. So I guess you should use `df = df.interpolate().`

Comment: @Elisa You're welcome. Also notice that I tryed to answer your other question from the comment before in my answer now.